# All numbers that are less than four units from zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Looking at a simple algebra question which is to graph "All numbers that are less than four units from zero."

The knee jerk response is to draw a number line with an open circle at -4 and a line to the left pointing at negative infinity. A second interpretation could be to highlight all numbers that are less than those numbers that are four units from zero. In which case that would be the entire number line.

All numbers that are more than four units from zero would clearly be x < -4 and x > 4.

Is there a mathematical standard on how the "all units less than" language should be interpreted?

Comment: My interpretation would be that "all units less than 4 units from 0" would be the set of $x$ such that $|x|<4$. I'm not sure why your first response (which is all $x$ such that $x<-4$) is somehow the "knee-jerk" response.

Comment: Mankind invented algebraic symbolism to get rid of the need to worrying about ambiguous and verbose ways of expressing mathematical formulae. You should rebel against a question setter who is reverting to long-dead terminology. (@Eeevee: if you read "$x$ from $y$" as "$y -x$", "four units from zero" can be read as a noun phrase denoting "-4", hence the possible reading as $x < -4$ rather than $|x| < 4$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've parsed the input as:

> All numbers that are less than (four units from zero)

but it is probably intended as:

> All numbers that are (less than four units) from zero

or in other words, all numbers whose distance from zero is less than four units.

Comment: The OP is asking whether there is a standard for this. There isn't. So your answer doesn't answer the question. (I also don't see why you think one reading is more likely than the other. I would agree with you if I knew that the the original statement was by a native English speaker, but we don't have that information. The grammatical structure of the statement as you interpret it is more complex than the OP's knee-jerk interpretation.)

Comment: The original statement was written by a native speaker of English. Actually it's from a well-known U.S. boarding school math workbook and is the product of a high school math department committee process. Since this particular math department is known to be quite rigorous, I was suspicious of a possible "deeper" interpretation than just  x < -4. For additional context, there are a number of other questions around it exploring how to graph functions with absolute values in them.

Comment: @RobArthan That's fair, I don't want to pretend to lay out a standard, which doesn't exist. The point of saying "probably" is to guard against that. Understanding natural language is a Bayesian thing. I have a prior that slightly favors $(-4,4)$ over $(-\infty,-4)$ as a thing that people want to discuss. More importantly, my likelihood function strongly disfavors rendering the condition $x<-4$ as "less than four units from zero", as "less than negative four" would be much more likely.